# Proxy Protocol on Elastic Load Balancing non-terminated SSL connection

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

For reasons we're not going to change, our application needs to handle the SSL connection, and not the ELB. The goal of using the Proxy Protocol is to get the client's IP address over an *SSL* connection.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol.html?ref_=9 indicates "Alternatively, you can use it if you are sending HTTPS requests and do not want to terminate the SSL connection on the load balancer. For more information, please visit the [Elastic Load Balancing Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#proxy-protocol)."

Unfortunately, it appears the guide that's linked to doesn't actually elaborate on this, and the basic documentation for the Proxy Protocol ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html ) fails in our environment when configured as described.

Does anyone have steps or a link for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy protocol (version 1) injects a single line into the data stream at the beginning of the connection, before SSL is negotiated by your server.  You don't get this information "over" an SSL connection; you get the information prior to SSL handshaking. Your server has to implement this capability and specifically be configured so that it can accept and understand it.  For an IPv4 connection, it looks like this:

```
PROXY TCP4 source-ip dest-ip source-port dest-port\r\n
```

The standard for the protocol is here:

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

Additional info in the ELB docs here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#proxy-protocol

---

Regarding Apache support, at least at the time AWS announced support for the proxy protocol...

> **“**neither Apache nor Nginx currently support the Proxy Protocol header inserted by the ELB**”**
>
> <sup>— http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol.html?ref_=9</sup>

That is subject to change, of course, but I didn't successfully google for any Apache support of the proxy protocol.  Of course, since Apache is open source, you could presumably hack it in there, though I am unfamiliar with the Apache source code.

Realizing that you don't want to change what you're doing now, I still would suggest that depending on your motivation for not wanting to change, there may still be a relatively simple solution.  It's a change, but not involving SSL on ELB.  What about running HAProxy behind ELB to terminate the SSL in front of Apache?  Since HAProxy 1.5 can terminate SSL and [appears to be able to](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-http-request) translate the proxy protocol string from ELB into an `X-Forwarded-For` header, as well as generate `X-SSL` headers to give your application information about the client's SSL cert (perhaps that's your motivation for terminating SSL at the app server instead of on the ELB?) ... so this might be an alternative.

Otherwise, I don't have suggestions unless Apache implements support in the future, or we can find some documentation to indicate that they already have.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suppose my real question is if it's possible to modify Apache to accommodate the extra string, and if so how?

Comment: @conrad10781 I'm not sure, but I've added some additional information to the answer in the hopes that it will at least be useful.

Comment: FYI, nginx now supports proxy protocol: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Answer (score 0):

For the newer [Network Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) which allow your application servers to terminate the TLS connections, you can still get the real IP addresses of your clients and avoid all the work of configuring proxy protocol on the ELBs and in the web server config by simply [configuring the target groups to use the servers' instance ids](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#proxy-protocol) rather than their IP addresses. Regardless of which web server you use, the real IPs of the clients will show up in the logs with no translation needed.

Just to follow up on Michael - sqlbot's answer discussing the [AWS support for proxy protocol on EC2 instances behind classic TCP elastic load balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html), the Apache module to use that implements the proxy protocol is [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html). Enabling it and updating the configuration properly will  correct the problem of logging IP addresses of users rather than the elastic load balancer's IPs.

To enable proxy protocol on the elastic load balancer you could use these aws cli commands described in the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html):

```
aws elb create-load-balancer-policy --load-balancer-name my-elb-name --policy-name my-elb-name-ProxyProtocol-policy --policy-type-name ProxyProtocolPolicyType --policy-attributes AttributeName=ProxyProtocol,AttributeValue=true
aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server --load-balancer-name my-elb-name --instance-port 443 --policy-names my-elb-name-ProxyProtocol-policy
aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server --load-balancer-name my-elb-name --instance-port 80 --policy-names my-elb-name-ProxyProtocol-policy
```

To enable use of proxy protocol in apache, in a server-wide or VirtualHost context, follow the [mod_remoteip documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) such as below:

```
<IfModule mod_remoteip.c>
  RemoteIPProxyProtocol On
  RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
  # The IPs or IP range of your ELB:
  RemoteIPInternalProxy 192.168.1.0/24
  # The IPs of hosts that may need to connect directly to the web server, bypassing the ELB (if applicable):
  RemoteIPProxyProtocolExceptions 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

You'll need to update the [LogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) wherever you have those defined (e.g. httpd.conf) to use %a rather than %h else the load balancer IP addresses will still appear.